# How to insert JSON object into Mysql database through javascript variable using VB.Net

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, vb.net

I want to convert my textbox value into json object through javascript variable and after the convertion need to insert the JSON Object into MySQL database using VB.Net code.
My Code as follows :

Client-Side :

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var Name = $('#txtName').val();
        var Username = $('#txtUsername').val();
        var Password = $('#txtPassword').val();
        if (Name != '' && Username != '' && Password != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
                data: '{Name: ' + Name + ',Username:' + Username + ',Password:' + Password  + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = data.d;
                    if (obj == 'true') {
                        $('#txtName').val('');
                        $('#txtUsername').val('');
                        $('#txtPassword').val('');
                        $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Please enter all the fields')
            return false;
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Server Side :

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function InsertData(ByVal Name As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    Dim msg As String = String.Empty
    Dim MySqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim query As String
    Dim dbcomm As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.53;charset=utf8;userid=root;password=password;allow user variables=true;database=information"
    MySqlConn.Open()
    query = "insert into information.userDetails(Name,Username,Password) VALUES(@Name,@Username,@Password)"
    dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(query, MySqlConn)
    reader = dbcomm.ExecuteReader
    Dim i As Integer = dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If i = 1 Then
        msg = "true"
    Else
        msg = "false"
    End If

    Return msg
    MySqlConn.Close()

End Function
```

But my json data always throughs error function. It doesn't enter into the success function it always calling error function. Please let me know what to do?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to properly send `json data`.

Appending `quotes and braces` manually requires `proper formatting` so if you even miss a single quote error will occur.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({Name:  Name ,Username: Username ,Password:Password});


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/InsertData",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = data.d;
            if (obj == 'true') {
               $('#txtName').val('');
               $('#txtUsername').val('');
               $('#txtPassword').val('');
               $('#lblmsg').html("Details Submitted Successfully");
               window.location.reload();
             }
         },
         error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this code too but still its showing error like  "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead." in the console. I can't understand where its showing in..

Comment: Which jquery version you are using ?

Comment: jquery version 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I used all jquery versions but my Jquery function doesn't working and showing error as  "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead." again again.